# Python: I'm making several lists to keep track of variables in a database

Tags: database, list, file-io, while-loop

## It's supposed to save each line in the text file into a list and split it based on commas and categorize them into multiple different lists. The error occurs at the while loop stating that the index is out of range.

```
lineCounter = 0
j = 0
file = open("savefile.txt","r") 
with open('savefile.txt', 'r') as f:
    string = [line.strip() for line in f]
for line in file:
    lineCounter += 1
while(j<lineCounter):
    tempList = string[j].split(',')
    firstName[j] = tempList[0]
    lastName[j] = tempList[1]
    postition[j] = tempList[2]
    department[j] = tempList[3]
    seniority[j] = tempList[4]
    vacationWeeks[j] = tempList[5]
    sickDays[j] = tempList[6]
    iD[j] = tempList[7]
    status[j] = tempList[8]
    j += 1
```

print firstName
file.close() # close the text file

Answer (score 0):

NVM the problem was that the list needed to be appended rather than replaced.